# html tags as string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to keep the value of textarea into hidden field using jquery.When I write "alert('yes');" inside textbox I want it display just as string but it is throwing an alert.How to make enable to take the html tag as string in jquery.In other words I want to take  tags as string from jquery.

```
 <div id=bedtype">
      @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.AddBedTypeInfo, new { @placeholder = "additional bed type info", @class = "textareaWidth" })
    </div>

$("#bedtype").text(addbedtype).html();
```

This works but then the textarea will vanish and div taje the html.

Comment: Show `HTML` code rendered on page

Comment: I have just textarea in page and has created hidden filed from jquery.

Comment: As far as I understand you are fetching value from text field and setting it in textarea? Are you sure you are setting it in textarea or some HTML div?

Comment: <div id=bedtype"> this syntax looks buggy,

Answer (score 0):

I think your last line seems wrong
You have done `$("#bedtype").text(addbedtype).html();`
Instead you need to do

```
$("#bedtype").html(addbedtype).text();
```

Comment: I am fetching value from textarea and setting it in hidden field.I want the <script>alert('1');</script> will appears as string rather than creating alert.

Comment: I tried as you said but still textarea will vanish and div takes the value of textarea.

Comment: $("#bedtype").prop("tagName") what does this returns?

Comment: Textarea doesnot vanish but it gives undefined as value @Parag.

Comment: $("#bedtype").prop("tagName") if this returns undefined then I am afraid that there is no textarea with id bedtype

Comment: bedtype is the id of div not of textarea.Am I supposed to take the id of textarea?

Comment: obviously If you want to put value in textarea then you should use id of the textarea

Comment: I used it but still it gives undefined and tagnames can be change so how does it works?

Comment: use this $("#bedtype textarea").val(textfieldVal)

Comment: It gives [object][object] and textarea vanished.